# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT from socket.io client

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, openshift

I am using Socket.io 1.4.8, server set up at [openshift](https://nodejstapchat-breathalert.rhcloud.com/socket.io/socket.io.js), and is running well.

I only got it to run after I went in to the socket.io server code and removed the explicit port in the url.

My problem now is that on the socket.io client side, I keep getting this error in the Chrome console:

> GET https://nodejstapchat-breathalert.rhcloud.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LN4EN7L net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT  socket.io.js:3511

I suspect, it is again the redundant port in the URL. How do I cleanly remove the ":8080" but from the URL?

Please advice if this is actually my problem, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the problem is the port, **8080** is the right port. I suggest you to check your Socket.io client code where you access the `io` var. Try this, replace:

```
io('https://nodejstapchat-breathalert.rhcloud.com:8080')
```

simply with:

```
io()
```

It should work. Please let me know.